# Google plus sharing

Tags: cordova, google-plus, phonegap-plugins

I want to share some text on Google+ from my Phonegap App compatible on iOS and Android platforms. I have followed the link http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery.

This link is working for Android but not for iOS. And also for Android I need to post or share some text. This sample only discusses for showing Tasks list only. I have searched a lot but unable to find any solution. Sharing on iOS can be done by plugins and I have done this successfully. But for Android I don't know how to do so as I am a newbie on Android so can't do native coding.

Please give me solution for sharing on google plus through Phonegap.

Comment: What is happening when you try? What pages are or aren't shown? Are there any error messages? There are a lot of steps and a lot of additional files to load - have you made sure you followed all of them?

Comment: I need to share some text on google plus. How can I achieve this in Android for Phonegap ?

Comment: If this is related to the original question, please provide the additional details. The question is too vague to answer. If this is an additional question from the origina, open it as a separate question.

Comment: As for now, I need to integrate google plus sharing for Android using Phonegap. I have created a plugin for iOS which is working properly. But for Android I am unable write Java code if plugin is to be used or find any relevant code for sharing texts if the link is to be followed  http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through the same issue. There's a plugin to share links or text on social network sites. This socialshare plugin is available on github link https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.

It helped me. I hope it helps you out. good luck! :)

Comment: Sharing to Google from IOS doesn't work with that Plugin though, or am I  missing something?